# sed system command in perl script

Tags: perl, shell, sed

I am trying to put the system command like below to the perl script, but 
sed expression contains both quotes and backticks and I am not sure how to escape all of them, so it will execute my system command exactly as I need.

Here is the example of the command:

```
mysql -u root -D porta-billing -e "..." | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g"
```

Comment: Don't do it that way! Use [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI).

Comment: I want to put a shell command to the script. not more. I dont want to learn a new handler for that

Comment: Calling the MySQL client and sed via `system` is much more error-prone than using DBI and native Perl commands, and DBI is not really that hard to learn. The ["outline usage"](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Outline-Usage) section of the docs is a good place to start.

Comment: Also, if you have an answer, please post it in the answer section instead of adding it to your question.

Comment: So, you're saying you don't want to learn perl but instead want to write a shell script inside a perl script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question you're asking is to use the `qx(...)` operator. `qx(...)` is the "choose your own delimiter" version of backticks.

```
my $output = qx[ ... ];
```

Or

```
my $output = qx( ... );
```

Or

```
my $output = qx! ... !;
```

It's easy to find a delimiter that won't clash with the characters in your command string.

But the answer to the question that you **should** be asking has two parts:

- Don't call `mysql` from your Perl program - use [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) instead.
- Don't call `sed` from your Perl program - use Perl code to manipulate your text.

I feel slightly nervous about the first part of my answer as I'm worried you will just take my hacky workaround and end up with an unmaintainable mess. Please take note of the advice in the second half - even if you ignore it in this case.